# How to get all blob storage(new or updated one) using azure functions time trigger

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have requirement where i need to get all the blob storage which are updated or added after a particular time duration.

Example :-  In container I have list of zip file as a blob, I need to get all the updated or newly added blob in a given interval like after every 1 hour I need to get all the newly added or updated blob.

So I have used azure function where created one time trigger function but could not able to get all the blob(updated or newly added).

Could anyone let me know how I can solve this problem.

function.json file

```
"bindings": [
{
  "name": "myTimer",
  "type": "timerTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "schedule": "0 */2 * * * *"
},
{
  "type": "blob",
  "name": "myBlob", 
  "path": "*****/******.zip",     
  "connection": "***************",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

],
  "disabled": false
}

index.js

```
module.exports = function(context, trigger, inputBlob) {
context.log(inputBlob);
//it's also available on context.bindings
context.log(context.bindings.inputBlob); // will log the same thing as above
context.done();
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far? Show us some code that you have written.

Comment: I have done some initial configuration on azure platform. Created a azure function  and inside create a function for time trigger with input as blob. I have created function.json file with code as below to get the input when time trigger function would run.

Comment: Index.js file as below  :-                                                                                       
module.exports = function(context, trigger, inputBlob) {
    context.log(inputBlob);
    //it's also available on context.bindings
    context.log(context.bindings.inputBlob); // will log the same thing as above
    context.done();
}

Comment: You would have to manually search for those files - bindings won't give you that. Why not run your function each time a new blob is changed (blob trigger)?

Comment: Actually the requirement is like it should be after a time interval. That is why i am not using blob Trigger.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Did you find any possible solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Mikhail : Any other solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, Functions work best if you use them in reactive way, i.e. when Function is run on Blob change event directly (or via Event Grid).

If you have to stick to timer and then find all changed Blobs, Azure Function bindings won't help you. In this case, remove the input binding that you were trying to declare and search for changed blobs with Blob Storage API. I believe [Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) supports listing the blobs, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is a good candidate for using an Azure Event Grid (now in the preview) solution with an event-driven blob storage publisher. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart).

Basically, there is no limitation for number of containers, blob storages either the Azure subscriptions. If your blob storage has been subscribed for the event interest, such as the blob has been created or deleted, the custom filtered event message can be delivered to the subscriber, for instance, the EventGridTrigger Function.

The following screen snippet shows  an example of the event-driven blob storages:

[image]

The following logs shows a received  an event message by function, when the blob has been deleted:

[image: logs]

Note, that the event message sent by blob storage publisher can be filtered in the subscription based on *subject* and/or *eventType* properties. In other  words, each subscription can tell to Event Grid for its event source interest.

In the case of streaming events and their analyzing, the Event Grid can be subscribed for Event Hub subscriber, see the following screen snippet:

[image: streaming]

All events from the source interest will ingest to the *Event Hub* which it represents an entry point of the  stream pipeline. The stream of the events, such as the event messages of the created/deleted blobs across the accounts and/or azure subscriptions is analyzing by ASA job based on the needs. The output of the ASA job will trigger an *Azure Function* to finish a business requirements.

More details about the Event Hub as a destination for Event Grid is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-event-grid-now-supports-event-hubs-as-a-destination/).

Comment: Thanks roman for your update but situation is bit different in my case I need to get the changed or newly added blob from storage account after time interval and make some processing and send it to other blob storage. For example :- Let say , in between 1 hour I need all the blob that are created or updated. It is like time trigger function but that wouldn't solve my problem.